# Any way to remove the pop up dialog on row drag?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

Tried searching the docs and online but i couldn't find anything.

Is there a way to remove the dialog pop when dragging rows? (See attached).

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: Hide it with css.

Comment: @ЕмилЦоков this is what i was trying to do, however its kind of hard for me to tell what the class is - any chance you know what it is?

Comment: Not sure also maybe try create custom drag and provide custom class you can hide see this : https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/966dde0b538315d4a2e14cf11b19820b31ad57c7/grid-packages/ag-grid-docs/documentation/doc-pages/drag-and-drop/examples/custom-drag-comp/dragSourceRenderer_react.tsx